# How to find out where my superannuation is invested

Tags: investing, australia, superannuation

I want to know more about where my superannuation money is being invested. When I log in to my account, it shows me which asset classes my money is invested in, and what percentage of my total portfolio is invested in each asset class.

I basically want more details about where my money is being invested in each asset class (especially shares, since this takes up about 80% of my portfolio) i.e. which companies my money has been invested in.

At this point I am not interested in opening a SMSF (self-managed super fund) since I do not have enough money invested at the moment to make that worthwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your super fund should be able to provide the mix of investments and their weightings for the investment option you have chosen. It should be readily available on their website but may be hard to find depending on the fund. If you can't find this information you should call your fund and ask where to find it or for a copy to be sent to you.

Here is an example from First State Super.

[image]

It actually lists the top 50 shares invested in that asset class, to see the remander you can check out the link: [First State Super](https://firststatesuper.com.au/investment-and-performance/investments/what-we-invest-in/australian)

Answer (score -2):

I was misinformed, removing this answer. I would delete it but I can't while it's accepted.

Comment: "*The portfolios that make up your fund are a bit of secret sauce from the superannuation provider.*"  That would NEVER fly in the US.  Every fund has to regularly disclose what it's holding are.  (I think it's quarterly.)

Comment: This is a bad answer showing no research and actually provides wrong information.